# How to make gallery image fade on hover to reveal details such as title, enlarge, visit site, etc?

Tags: jquery, hover, fade, image-gallery

I've seen a nice image gallery hover effect used quite a lot lately and I'm just wondering whether anybody knows of a good way to recreate such an effect. The effect is when you hover over an image, the image fades out or a div fades in showing links etc over the image.

It's similar to the one found here: http://cssnack.com/ and here: http://designsnack.com/

I've created something similar in the past, but remember having trouble with the opacity fades  in IE. Any tips would be great or even directions to a good tutorial for a similar effect.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/balupton/FZG3v/

Comment: Thanks for you're help balupton! That's the sort of thing I was thinking of. I'll take a closer look at your example as soon as I can.

Thanks Again :)

Comment: Don't suppose you still have the working example up anywhere do you? :o)

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript and put this in a loop with a time lag and slide the value of MyVariable from Transparent to Opaque.

`document.getElementById("MyImage").style.MozOpacity=MyVariable`